# Sending iPhone App Source

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have developed an app for someone and want to send it to them so they can submit it under their profile etc. What are the bare bones I can send, all of the graphics/videos etc are in the main project folder but the project folder is huge because of the builds folder, what all do I need to include when I send this for him to be able to open it/sign it/upload it? Builds only comes from compiling right so he doesn't need this folder at all??..

Comment: Do you not use source control?

Comment: I honestly don't even know what that is. I have no use for this code once its his and I don't want any credit or use of it in the future so I was assuming I can just send him the class folder and the main project folder and he can just compile it and do what he wants no?

Comment: If someone sent you those files would you be able to compile the whole app? If yes, then the answer is yes. Try something for yourself; Copy the files you think you need into a different folder. Then open up that project and try a build.

Comment: @Steve : Many people do not check large videos into source control.  Huge binaries and such are sometimes separately versioned and backed-up elsewhere.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I fail to see your point as the OP indicated they "don't even know what [source control] is."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the build folder before sending someone the project directory.  When they build the app on their Mac for testing or for submission, Xcode will (re)create a build or a DerivedData directory (depending on which version of Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need the builds folder. Frankly I'm kind of surprised that it is located in the same directory as the project, since usually (by default) XCode manages the build location and puts it somewhere else. I would go into the project settings and change this build location to a more sensible place.